# use socket.io-client-cpp in a iOS static library error happens

Tags: objective-c, socket.io, sdk

i need to use sokcet.io in a static library.
i use objc to write the SDK.

`pod lib create LibName` 
then follow then command choose the `objc` language and have a `demo project`
when done, 
* add  `s.dependency 'SocketIO-Client-CPP'` in the `LibName.podspec`
* `cd Example` 
* `pod install`

then just as the tutorial   create a new file in `Development Pods`
https://gist.github.com/tooolkit/72dd5e95933fa27a3c59f329bfcc92c6
build 
 first it message 
 `libTestSocketIO.a(error_code.o)' does not contain bitcode`
i turn off the bitcode in `build settings`
then it message 
 `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "typeinfo for std::bad_cast", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::bad_lexical_cast in libTestSocketIO.a(sio_packet.o)`

but`lipo -info libUniversalRelease.a` 
`Architectures in the fat file: libUniversalRelease.a are: armv7 arm64 i386 x86_64`
how could i solve it ?

Comment: I using swift framework Socket.io. It's work perfect in obj-c.

Comment: Follow install guideline. It works well in obj-c.

Comment: @Bimawa i know swift version, if i'm writing the app i can use swift, but i am writing SDK in objc can't use the swift

Comment: @PhineasHuang i use it correct if i new a project. but i am writing the static library.

Comment: @tooolkit no you want not. I use a swift version in my Obj-c project. its work fine with Carthage. because my cocoa pods do not use frameworks.

Comment: Maybe you could try to add libs and heads in your new project.
./Pods/SocketIO-Client-CPP/libUniversalRelease.a
./Pods/SocketIO-Client-CPP/Headers